# How to step into function of a dll when you have the .pdb file and the C++ source code with VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, step-into

I am trying to debug a dynamic library I have wrote used by an application inside Visual Studio 2010. I can step into until a function of my dll, but I can't step into deeper and see the source code. If I open the *Disassembly* window, then I can step into the ASM code but I don't see the source code or any symbol.

I have build a .dll and an import .lib. The .pdb (`/Zi`) file associated to the dll has been built too (with `/DEBUG`). Optimisation are disabled (`/Od`).

My application links the import lib with a `#pragma comment(lib, "myImport.lib")` because the application has a build tool I can't configure myself.

My application is run in debug, and in the *Modules* of the debugger I can see my dll is loaded as well as the symbols.

I have also check the *Options > Debugging > General Enable Just My Code* option is disable.

How to force VS2010 to step into the functions of my dll?

Comment: does your project know the location of the dll's pdb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you could expect it was a compile incompatibility. The dll was compiled for CLR runtime (`/clr`). I guess because a default configuration of VS2010. Since I removed this option everything can be debug as usual.

Answer (score 0):

We have a slightly different setup where we launch another application we don't have the source code from which, in turn, loads a dll built by ourselves. To debug into it we use the Visual Studio command Debug / Attach to Process... Maybe this command could lead you to a successful debugging into your dll's sources.